# How to simplify two li into arrays using Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, foreach

I have this bit of code, how would I simplify it into a for each loop using two arrays.

```
listLength = $('.list-items li').size();

    if (listLength >= 4){

        $('.pagination ul li:lt(3)').addClass('selected');
    }else if (listLength >= 3){

        $('.pagination ul li:lt(5)').addClass('selected');

    }else if (listLength >= 2){

        $('.pagination ul li:lt(7)').addClass('selected');

    }else if (listLength >= 1){

        $('.pagination ul li:lt(9)').addClass('selected');

    }else if (listLength >= 0){
        $('.pagination ul li:lt(11)').addClass('selected');

    } else{

    }
```

I know I can do something like this...

```
list = $('.list-items li');
page = $('.pagination ul li');

$.each(list, function(i, item) {
   //do something here
});
```

or ...

```
var i;
list = $('.list-items li');
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    //do something here
}
```

but I'm unsure how.

Comment: telescope to see the moon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
listLength = $('.list-items li').size();
var temp = 11 - 2 * Math.min(listLength,4);
$('.pagination ul li:lt('+ temp +')').addClass('selected');
```